# Trouble allowing external public access to my webserver

Tags: flask, webserver, centos7, firewall, portforwarding

I am attempting to setup a Web Server in my home using an old laptop. Here is what I have done:

1. TCP and UDP tested
2. CentOS 7 installed
3. opened port 80 and 8000 with firewall-cmd (confirmed open as I am able to access my Web Server within my own LAN)
4. opened port 80 and 8000 with my ATT Uverse Router (confirmed open with yougetsignal.com)
5. I am running a Python Flask application I have tried it on both port 80 and 8000.

I am able to connect to the flask app within my own LAN using the local IP but cannot connect externally by using my public IP.

Note: I am able to connect to it externally by setting the web server to DMZPlus mode (opening all ports) in my router, but it is very insecure.

Can someone please tell me what I am missing? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the flask server listening on? Is it bound to 0.0.0.0?

Check the **Externally Visible Server** Section on this page.

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/

Comment: It was a combination of binding to 0.0.0.0 and that I cannot access it from my LAN using the public IP, but it works from an external source. Thanks for your help